# What's the direction of speedtest download/upload?

Tags: networking, network-speed

What's the direction of `download` and `upload` in speedtest?

[image]

The Server is Hong Kong STC, my local is: `12.34.156.228`.

When I test the speed, you can see the `DOWNLOAD` 28.38Mbps and `UPLOAD` 22.77Mbps.

I want to know the direction, is the `DOWNLOAD` means `STC` -> `local`? or on the contrary?

Comment: I would recommend you remove your IP address from the post for security purposes. There is no reason to have it listed.

Comment: it‘s a example ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download would be from STC -> local

Upload would be from your IP -> STC

Download means how quickly you can download things from the internet (movies, music, files)

Upload means how quickly you can transfer files out to the internet.